# Powershell - find name base on description

Tags: powershell

My code:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq "James Kent"} -Properties Description | where {$_.Description -Notlike "Services User"} | select Name
```

I tried the code above and it still display both account. So I have users with 2 accounts. One account being a regular account and one being a services account. I only want to display the regular account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, and works for me (with changed account variable). That means you should check the account and the "Services User". Break down the pipeline step-by-step to verify things work.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq "James Kent"} -Properties Description
```

This should output the two accounts, along with their description as headers. According to your errors, this part is working well so you probably don't even need to check it.

However, it still may be good to do to check that the "Description" property looks fine:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq "James Kent"} -Properties Description | select Description
```

If those match what you have written, then add the next element to the pipeline:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq "James Kent"} -Properties Description | where {$_.Description -Notlike "Services User"}
```

For this part, it is more important to see what it outputs. From what you are saying, this will output both accounts, but this is not what you want. The most likely case is that "Services User" is not exactly the description of your other account. Compare it to the output of the snippet above this one.

I hope this helps, it's just classic debugging. You could also use something like the `DistinguishedName` property to compare the two accounts, it might be more reliable than the description (which is not a mandatory property).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You should use another switch. Instead using -not like, you should use -ne or -eq:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq "James Kent"} -Properties Description | where {$_.Description -ne "Services User"} | select Name
```

Or:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq "James Kent"} -Properties Description | where {$_.Description -eq "regular account"} | select Name
```

Of course when you use above switches you must check the string in description. It must be equal to string in where condition.

Answer (score 0):

Interest... It works when I add `"*service*"`

Thanks for summing up the issue guys.